# Logical comparison of elements from named list vs named vector in R

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I read through a number of threads but couldn't really find a good explanation.

I have a dataset (dataframe) where I calculated the mean value of each column. I now want to do some logical comparisons between these values. I used `lapply` to get the means

`means_list <- lapply(dataset_df, mean)`

which outputs a named list. But when I try to compare two elements of this list, e.g.

`means_list["condition1"] > means_list["condition2"]`

I get an error ("comparison of these types is not implemented").

I don't get that error if I use `sapply` instead so that I'm working with a named vector. I can also get around the error by converting the list to a dataframe with `as.data.frame` first.

So, I feel like I'm doing something wrong when subsetting a named list here but I don't quite understand how. Is there a correct way to subset the list so that I can do the logical comparison? Or is this not possible with named lists?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Comment: Thank you, that explains it really well. Kind of tricky that double brackets are only really required for lists. I can already tell that I will probably forget to do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to the element of a list by its name, you have to use double brackets:

```
means_list[["condition1"]] > means_list[["condition2"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I will look up the difference between `[ ]`and `[[ ]]` now!